Why was a male slave given precedence over a female slave in Nasai 3446?
It is narrated in https://sunnah.com/nasai:3446:

"Aishah had a male slave and a female slave. She said: 'I wanted to set them free, and I mentioned that to the Messenger of Allah. He said: Start with the male slave before the female slave.'"

Why was a male slave given precedence over a female slave over here? Are males worth more than females in the eyes of Allah?

The male is freed first because otherwise the female will be a free woman married to a slave which is contrary to status as a woman should be married to a man who is above or at least equal to her status, otherwise she gets a choice to annul the marriage.

I don't understand. Can you elaborate on your answer a bit more? My apologies.

@UmH I don't know why al-Albani regarded this hadith as sahih at all. Since both al-'Uqayli and ibn Hazm regarded it as weak as mentioned by a-Shawkani and ibn Qayyim. Ibn Hazm even denied that this hadith is any support for two married slaves since their status is nowhere mentioned. Further, in case of married slaves we have the known hadith of Barira -for example in Sahih Muslim- giving the freed woman the choice to stay under her husband or leave.

@Medi1Saif I don't know where al-Albani has classed it as Sahih, I checked in one or two places and his classification was Da'eef. As for the grading of Darussalam as Hassan it is explained in the print edition. You can see a screenshot of it here.

@UmH I found it here.

@Medi1Saif Seems like the hadith of Barira is the reason why the hadith prefers the man be freed first. Having the option of divorce is only in non-ideal situations and it only exists (according to Shafiis and Malikis) because of the mismatch between a free woman and a slave husband.

There would be two problems if the woman was freed first, she would not really be free. She has probably no safe place to go without marriage because the slaves were usually foreigners; maharam would be unavailable or also slaves,
If she was married to the male slave, she would not really change her status because he couldn't leave, so that she would be in the same household. The marriage would still be valid, but the liberation imperfect.
Freeing both at the same time would be as good.
If they intend to marry, it makes sense to free the man first because the man may arrange the marriage and they may live as free people. This is most likely the background of this.
If she was married to another free man, the two persons would have no link and they would not have been mentioned together.

The hadith is as follows:

عن عائشة، أنها كان لها غلام وجارية زوج فقالت يا رسول الله إني أريد أن أعتقهما فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم إن أعتقتهما فابدئي بالرجل قبل المرأة
Aishah had a male slave and a female slave who were married. She said: “O Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), I want to free them both.” The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: “If you free them, then start with the man before the woman.”
— Ibn Majah

The following are two main reason for freeing the male first, according to scholars who have commented on the hadith:
To preserve the marriage:
The purpose of freeing the male first is so that equality of status is maintained between the spouses so that the marriage between them is preserved. A husband must have a higher or at least an equal social status to his wife. If he is of lower status then the marriage is only possible between them if both the wife and her guardians agree to forego their rights.
If a slave woman is freed then according to the law she gets an option to annul her previous marriage. An example of this is that Barirah was given the choice to annul her marriage when she was freed and she adopted the option:

أن زوج، بريرة كان عبدا يقال له مغيث كأني أنظر إليه يطوف خلفها يبكي، ودموعه تسيل على لحيته، فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم لعباس ‏ يا عباس ألا تعجب من حب مغيث بريرة، ومن بغض بريرة مغيثا ‏.‏ فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏لو راجعته.‏ قالت يا رسول الله تأمرني قال إنما أنا أشفع.‏ قالت لا حاجة لي فيه
Barira's husband was a slave called Mughith, as if I am seeing him now, going behind Barira and weeping with his tears flowing down his beard. The Prophet (ﷺ) said to Abbas, "O Abbas ! are you not astonished at the love of Mughith for Barira and the hatred of Barira for Mughith?"
The Prophet (ﷺ) then said to Barira, "Why don't you return to him?" She said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Do you order me to do so?" He said, "No, I only intercede for him." She said, "I am not in need of him."
— Bukhari

According to the majority of the jurists this option is only given if the husband is a slave, and is not given if he is free. Hence if the husband is freed first then this option will not be given and the marriage will not be annulled. This will benefit the husband as he won't lose anything due to the act of freeing.
The Hanafis disagree with this as according to them every married slave woman is given the choice on being freed, even if her husband is already free.
Because freeing a male is more virtuous:
The second reason is that freeing a male slave is more virtuous than freeing a female slave, so it is preferable to do that first. A male is more beneficial e.g. he may take part in Jihad. The fact that freeing a male is more virtuous is also derived from the following hadith:

أيما امرئ مسلم أعتق امرأ مسلما كان فكاكه من النار يجزي كل عضو منه عضوا منه وأيما امرئ مسلم أعتق امرأتين مسلمتين كانتا فكاكه من النار يجزي كل عضو منهما عضوا منه
Any Muslim man who frees a Muslim man, then it is his salvation from the Fire - each of his limbs suffices for a limb of himself. And any Muslim man that frees two Muslim women, they are his salvation from the Fire - each of their limbs suffices for a limb of himself.
— Jami at-Tirmidhi

Since it implies that the reward of freeing one male is equal to the reward of freeing two females. Also a female slave may face more difficulty than a male in finding the means to support herself after being freed, while during her slavery it is the responsibility of her owner to provide for her.

Regarding the narration found in Jami at-Tirmidhi, does this narration imply that men are inherently more virtuous than woman, or is it consequential in the sense that by freeing a man, he will be able to part take in more virtuous activities due to the general capabilities of a man?
